# Custom stylesheet is not being applied as expected

Tags: css, django, code-snippets, django-ckeditor

I use Code Snippet in django-ckeditor

but in the Target Page it can‘t work when I change the css

whatever I change in css like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/highlight/styles/monokai_sublime.css">
```

the css is always default.css

So what is the problem?

my base.html is:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/highlight/styles/monokai_sublime.css">
<script src="/static/highlight/highlight.pack.js"></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your settings I would set `STATIC_URL = /static/` and `STATIC_DIRS = path.to.static.files`.

Then in your `base.html` template, at the top `{% load staticfiles %}`. Furthermore, you can use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles/monokai_sublime.css' %}">` (assuming that's how your path is setup).